# Will SQL update affect its subquery during the update run?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, postgresql

I'm just composing a complex update query which looks more or less like this:

```
update table join
    (select y, min(x) as MinX 
     from table
     group by y) as t1
    using (y)
set x = x - MinX
```

Which means that the variable `x` is updated based on the subquery, which also processes variable `x` - but **couldn't this `x` already be modified by the running update command**? Isn't this a problem? I mean, in normal programming you normally have to handle this explicitly, i.e. store new value to some other place from the old value and after the job is done, replace the old value with new... but **how will SQL database do this?**

I'm not interested in a single observation or experiment. I would like to have a snippet from the docs or sql standard that will say what is the defined behaviour in this case. I'm using MySQL, but answers valid also for other PostgresQL, Oracle, etc. and especially **for SQL standard in general** are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What database engine, and are you selecting from the same table as you're updating?

Comment: @MarcusAdams, from the same table - consider it a final sql query. Using InnoDB, but the more gerenal answer (engine -> mysql -> SQL) the better.

Answer (score 5):

** **Edited** **

**Selecting from the target table**

From [13.2.9.8. Subqueries in the FROM Clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html):

> Subqueries in the FROM clause can return a scalar, column, row, or table. Subqueries in the FROM clause cannot be correlated subqueries, unless used within the ON clause of a JOIN operation.

So, yes, you can perform the above query.

**The problem**

There are really two problems here. There's concurrency, or ensuring that no one else changes the data out from under our feet. This is handled with locking. Dealing with the actual modification of new versus old values is handled with derived tables.

**Locking**

In the case of your query above, with InnoDB, MySQL performs the SELECT first, and acquires a read (shared) lock on each row in the table individually. If you had a WHERE clause in the SELECT statement, then only the records you select would be locked, where ranges would cause any gaps to be locked as well.

A [read lock](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html) prevents any other query from acquiring write locks, so records can't be updated from elsewhere while they're read locked.

Then, MySQL acquires a write (exclusive) lock on each of the records in the table individually. If you had a WHERE clause in your UPDATE statement, then only the specific records would be write locked, and again, if the WHERE clause selected a range, then you would have a range locked.

Any record that had a read lock from the previous SELECT would automatically be escalated to a write lock.

A [write lock](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html) prevents other queries from obtaining either a read or write lock.

You can use [Innotop](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDgQFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/innotop/&ei=Lp-ET9a9N4_6ggfUypDfBw&usg=AFQjCNFokDHQXNb8OTM_d62fCB5N0UmkWQ&sig2=O6-gRmP-64PyEZkgiqNN2w) to see this by running it in Lock mode, start a transaction, execute the query (but don't commit it), and you will see the locks in Innotop. Also, you can view the details without Innotop with `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`.

**Deadlocks**

Your query is vulnerable to a deadlock if two instances were run at the same time. If query A got read locks, then query B got read locks, query A would have to wait for query B's read locks to release before it could acquire the write locks. However, query B isn't going to release the read locks until after it finishes, and it won't finish unless it can acquire write locks. Query A and query B are in a stalemate, and hence, a deadlock.

Therefore, you may wish to perform an explicit table lock, both to avoid the massive amount of record locks (which uses memory and affects performance), and to avoid a deadlock.

An alternative approach is to use SELECT ... FOR UPDATE on your inner SELECT. This starts out with write locks on all of the rows instead of starting with read and escalating them.

**Derived tables**

For the inner SELECT, MySQL creates a [derived temporary table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html). A derived table is an actual non-indexed copy of the data that lives in the temporary table that is automatically created by MySQL (as opposed to a temporary table that you explicitly create and can add indexes to).

Since MySQL uses a derived table, that's the temporary old value that you refer to in your question. In other words, there's no magic here. MySQL does it just like you'd do it anywhere else, with a temporary value.

You can see the derived table by doing an EXPLAIN against your UPDATE statement (supported in MySQL 5.6+).

Comment: *"MySQL doesn't let you select from the same table that you're trying to update"* - Marcus, this is not true. The query works exactly as I posted it.

Comment: @Tomas, Ah, you're right. MySQL allows selecting from the target table with a JOIN clause. This is back to a lock question. I've edited my answer above.

Comment: Marcus, thanks for the effort, however I'm not sure this answers the question. Your citations of the docs refer to the subqueries in the select statements' from clause. My question rather states: **what is the defined behaviour for subqueries of the update statement?**

Comment: @Tomas, when you do a JOIN in an UPDATE statement, you are setting columns in the target table by selecting values from the JOINed table. The subquery is not in your UPDATE statement, it's in the SELECT statement that MySQL performs.

Comment: So you argue that there is some implicit SELECT statement, which I haven't wrote directly, and everything in the docs that is valid for SELECT is also valid for this UPDATE? Is this somehow supported in the documentation? You might be right of course, but I'd like to know what is the **defined** behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

A proper RDBMS uses `statement level read consistency`, which ensures the statement sees (selects) the data as it was at the time the statement began. So the scenario you are afraid of, won't occur.

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has this in the 11.2 [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/consist.htm#BABHFAIJ)

> A consistent 
>   result set is provided for every query, guaranteeing data consistency,
>   with no action by the user. An implicit query, such as a query implied
>   by a WHERE clause in an UPDATE statement, is guaranteed a consistent
>   set of results. However, each statement in an implicit query does not
>   see the changes made by the DML statement itself, but sees the data as
>   it existed before changes were made.

Answer (score 0):

Although its been noted you SHOULDN'T be able to do an update to a table based on its own data, you should be able to adjust the MySQL syntax to allow for it via

```
update Table1, 
       (select T2.y, MIN( T2.x ) as MinX from Table1 T2 group by T2.y ) PreQuery
  set Table1.x = Table1.x - PreQuery.MinX
  where Table1.y = PreQuery.y
```

I don't know if the syntax goes a different route using JOIN vs the comma list version, but by the complete prequery you do would have to be applied first for its result completed ONCE, and joined (via the WHERE) to actually perform the update.

Comment: 1) *"Although its been noted you SHOULDN'T be able to do an update to a table based on its own data"* - DRapp, do you have any support for this claim? Can you please site the docs? 2) you just wrote the same query as I did! Maybe I misunderstood you but I didn't get the point of your answer...

Comment: @Thomas, yes, I rewrote, just used older style syntax without JOIN clause, but used the explicit where clause.  Another person from another correlated update had a similar problem with using JOIN syntax and it failed.  When changing to comma listed table sources and WHERE clause, it worked for them.  That was my only point of not using the "JOIN" version.

Comment: Well, but this is not my problem, my query works fine. My question is different - see its last paragraph.