# Is there an alternative approach to this (unallowed) UPDATE with a nested SELECT?

Tags: mysql

I have an existing table of contacts that has about 140k records in it. I am introducing a parent table (let's call them "parent_contacts") such that one parent_contact can have many contacts; but initially, parent_contacts will be seeded to have one record for every contact that currently exists in the database.

I thought I was being clever in trying something like the following, which I now understand is not allowed (assume all the necessary parent_contact records have been created ahead of time):

```
UPDATE contacts
SET contacts.parent_id = 
  (SELECT parent_contacts.id FROM parent_contacts
   WHERE NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT * FROM contacts AS c WHERE c.parent_id = parent_contacts.id) LIMIT 1)
```

(If not readily apparent, the idea here being to set the parent_id of each contact to the id of the first parent_contact that another contact isn't already linked to)

Since this particular approach is not possible, is there another way of doing this that doesn't involve executing 140k individual update statements?

FOLLOW-UP: I resolved this by introducing a temporary child_id on the parent table, which I then removed after the seeding was finished. But in the context of the original question, I think Tony's answer below sounds apt.

Comment: Why are you picking arbitrary records to link?  Don't you want to link the contact to its parent contact, say, based on matching names?

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have noted -- the parent objects really only serve as a way to collect related records (or will be used this way moving forward; initially they will only have the one record on them). They are little more than an id for other things to point to, so exactly which one gets chosen by the child record isn't important.

Comment: I just wonder whether this case wouldn't be somehow related to [my question about update-select query, which definitely is NOT prohibited](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091788/will-sql-update-affect-its-subquery-during-the-update-run)... Look there, maybe you find some inspiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have done this backwards

Add Parent_id to contacts (no constraint yet!)
Update Contacts filling Parent_id with a unique number.
Create ParentContracts, Don't put Identity in or Primary key.

The backfill ParentContacts with a Insert into ParentContacts Select Parent_id, .... From Contacts

Add the Identity (don't forget seed to next value) and Primary key to ParentContacts
Add the foreign key constraint to Contacts.

Nice easy steps and easy to check each one instead of this whole cloth manouvre you are trying now.