# Copy datasets with n:m-relation

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, insert, many-to-many

I would like to use the single SQL-statement

```
insert into T (...) select ... from T where ...
```

to copy a lot of datasets. My problem is that there are N:M-relationships from table `T` to other tables and these have to be copied too. How can I do this, if I do not know which original dataset belongs to which copied dataset? Let me demonstrate by example.

#### Content of the database before:

Table `T`:

```
ID  | COL1 | COL2    
-----------------
1   | A    | B
2   | C    | D
```

N:M-table references table U from table T (table U is not shown):

```
T   | U              
---------
1   | 100
1   | 101
2   | 100
2   | 102
```

My copy operation where [???] is the part I do not know:

```
insert into T (COL1, COL2) select COL1, COL2 from T
insert into NM (T, U) select [???]
```

#### Content of the database after:

Table `T`:

```
ID  | COL1 | COL2
-----------------
1   | A    | B
2   | C    | D
3   | A    | B
4   | C    | D
```

N:M-table:

```
T   | U
---------
1   | 100
1   | 101
2   | 100
2   | 102
3   | 100
3   | 101
4   | 100
4   | 102
```

Notice:

- I have thousands of datasets (not just two)
- I want to use 'insert ... select' to get a better performance

Comment: I don't understand the question, especially the last sentence. Just make whatever `select` you want - join multiple tables as you need, that will produce one resultant table, and this will be inserted. That's it!

Comment: @Tomas, sorry I missunderstand the question :(

Comment: @Tomas: I want to copy from a table into the same table.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem - I had quite a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10091788/684229), and it shouldn't be a problem. So prepare your `select` subquery as you would normally do it and then try to put it under insert statement, without any fear.

Comment: I have added a little example, in your 'quite similar question' you make an update. I want to make an insert and do not know the inserted ids.

Comment: Where did these `3` and `4` come from? If table `T` had ids from 1 to 1000, then you'd want 1000 new rows to be inserted with ids from 1001 to 2000?

Comment: ids should not be supplied to insert, id should be "auto_increment" field and should be generated automatically by mysql. So the inner select should select only other fields, not `id`.

Comment: the id colum is a primary key with auto-inc.

Answer (score 5):

If you are lucky enough to run the current **PostgreSQL 9.1**, there is an elegant and fast solution with a *single command* using the new [**data-modifying CTEs**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING).

No such luck with **MySQL** which does not support [Common Table Expressions (CTE)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html), not to mention data-modifying CTE.

Assuming `(col1, col2)` is initially unique:

#### Query 1

- You can easily pick arbitrary slices from the table in this case.
- No sequence numbers for `t.id` will be wasted.

```
WITH s AS (
    SELECT id, col1, col2
    FROM   t
--  WHERE  some condition
    )
    ,i AS (
    INSERT INTO t (col1, col2)
    SELECT col1, col2   -- I gather from comments that id is a serial column
    FROM   s
    RETURNING id, col1, col2
    )
INSERT INTO tu (t, u)
SELECT i.id, tu.u
FROM   tu
JOIN   s ON tu.t = s.id
JOIN   i USING (col1, col2);
```

If `(col1, col2)` is **not unique**, I see two other ways:

#### Query 2

- Use the [window function `row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) to make non-unique rows unique.
- `INSERT` rows without holes in the `t.id` space just like in the query above.

```
WITH s AS (
    SELECT id, col1, col2
         , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2) AS rn
    FROM   t
--  WHERE some condition
    )
    ,i AS (
    INSERT INTO t (col1, col2)
    SELECT col1, col2
    FROM   s
    RETURNING id, col1, col2
    )
    ,r AS (
    SELECT *
         , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2) AS rn
    FROM   i
    )
INSERT INTO tu (t, u)
SELECT r.id, tu.u
FROM   r
JOIN   s USING (col1, col2, rn)    -- match exactly one id per row
JOIN   tu ON tu.t = s.id;
```

#### Query 3

- This is based on the same idea that @ypercube already supplied, but all in one query.
- If there are holes in numbers space for current `t.id`, sequence numbers will be burnt for the new rows accordingly.
- Don't forget to **reset your sequence** beyond the new maximum or you will get duplicate key errors for new inserts in `t` that draw the default for `id` from the sequence. I integrated this as final step into the command. Fastest & safest this way.

```
WITH s AS (
    SELECT max(id) AS max_id
    FROM   t
    )
    ,i AS (
    INSERT INTO t (id, col1, col2)
    SELECT id + s.max_id, col1, col2
    FROM   t, s
    )
    ,j AS (
    INSERT INTO tu (t, u)
    SELECT tu.t + s.max_id, tu.u
    FROM   tu, s
    )
SELECT setval('t_id_seq', s.max_id + s.max_id)
FROM   s;
```

Details about [setval()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-sequence.html) in the manual.

#### Test setup

For a quick test.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t (id serial primary key, col1 text, col2 text);
INSERT INTO t (col1, col2) VALUES 
 ('A', 'B')
,('C', 'D');

CREATE TEMP TABLE tu (t int, u int);
INSERT INTO tu VALUES
 (1, 100)
,(1, 101)
,(2, 100)
,(2, 102);

SELECT * FROM t;
SELECT * FROM tu;
```

There was a somewhat [similar question recently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7391090/939860), where I provided a somewhat similar answer. Plus alternatives for version **8.3** without CTEs and window functions.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Lock (both) tables or make sure that only this script is running. Disable FK checks.

Step 2. Use these two `INSERT` statements, in this order:

```
INSERT INTO NM 
    (T, U) 
  SELECT 
      T + maxID, U
  FROM 
      NM
    CROSS JOIN
      ( SELECT MAX(ID) AS maxID 
        FROM T
      ) AS m

INSERT INTO T 
    (ID, COL1, COL2) 
  SELECT 
      ID+maxID, COL1, COL2 
  FROM 
      T
    CROSS JOIN
      ( SELECT MAX(ID) AS maxID 
        FROM T
      ) AS m
```

Step 3. Re-enable FKs.

Comment: And don't forget to reset the sequence for your serial column afterwards.