# Multiple Table INSERT Queries in single SQL Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert queries into multiple tables using the following code. I have tried without the TRANSACTION and it will not work, individually they work. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
$query = mysql_query("BEGIN;  
INSERT INTO `uc` (`ANO`, `CNO`, `P`) VALUES ('$ano', '$cno', '$p');  
INSERT INTO `ct` (`ANO`, `CNO`, `RNO`) VALUES ('$ano','$cno','$rno');  
COMMIT;");   

$query_run = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Ah, multiple tables - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471757/insert-rows-into-multiple-tables-in-a-single-query-selecting-from-an-involved-t

Comment: You should upgrade to PDO

Comment: if you were using mysqli you could use mysqli_multi_query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "BEGIN";
mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

$query = "INSERT INTO `uc` (`ANO`, `CNO`, `P`) VALUES ('$ano', '$cno', '$p')";
mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

$query = "INSERT INTO `ct` (`ANO`, `CNO`, `RNO`) VALUES ('$ano','$cno','$rno')";
mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

$query = "COMMIT";
mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
```