# SQL and relations between tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

For serveral times I've been returning to understanding of database relational theory, and still I don't have success. I'll try once more.

Let's say I have two tables:
animals:

```
CREATE TABLE animals (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
```

and food:

```
CREATE TABLE food (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, food TEXT);
```

What I need is to make this two tables connected. For example, I want to select 'pig' from **animals** table and recive all the things the pig can eat from **food** table.
I just don't get how to relate them. I belive I can add a foreign key to **food** table, which would link to the primary key of **animal** table, but there is an issue I can't figure out:

What if I make entries to the database from, for example, a web form, where I enter animal name and product which it eats. The animal name goes to the first table and automatically recieves an id. It just autoincrements. So, in order to make it a relation for the second table I must to select the new ID from the first table! So we got THREE sql requests:

1) `INSERT INTO animals (name) VALUES ('pig);`

2) `SELECT id FROM animals WHERE name='pig';` (we store it in a variable, does not really matters for now)

3) `INSERT INTO food (product, animal_id) VALUES ('something', 'id of a pig');`

I just feel that it is wrong.
Or my mind is just not capable of understanding such complex abstractions.

Please advice.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres?

Comment: Well, Postgress can into arrays, and this would be much easier, but what I want is, well, generic way, which would work with all database MSs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how you implement such a many-to-many relationship:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

And you can accomplish the task you describe with a ***single*** query using a [data-modifying CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471757/insert-rows-into-multiple-tables-in-a-single-query-selecting-from-an-involved-t/10472136#10472136):

```
WITH ins AS (
   INSERT INTO animals (name) VALUES ('pig')
   RETURNING animal_id  -- return generated ID immediately
   )
INSERT INTO animal_food (food_id, animal_id)  -- m:m link table
SELECT food_id, animal_id  -- food_id passed as 2nd param
FROM   ins;
```

Assuming we operate with a known-existing food (like it was select from a drop-down menu. Else you need one more step to look up the food or possibly `INSERT` a row there, too:

- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324)

... still a single query.

The linked answer provides some insight in the more tricky matter of race conditions with concurrent transactions.

Answer (score 3):

You need a junction table, that related `Animals` and `Food`.  This would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE AnimalFoods (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    AnimalId int references Animal(id),
    FoodId int references Food(id)
);
```

You can then answer your questions using various joins among these tables.

Answer (score 1):

Can an animal eat multiple foods? If not, then you can have `animal` be the primary key on `food` the food table. If `animal` can have multiple foods, then you can have an auto increment ID (just like the one in the `animal` table) in the `food` table. As jWeaver pointed out, have a parentID in the `food` table as the foreign key referencing the `animal` table.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `animal` table with `parentId` and then in your `food` table use that `parentId` column to refer.

**Example:**

```
Animal(ParentId integer, NAME TEXT);
```

and

```
Food(FoodId integer, ParentId integer, Name Text);
```

That's it. Make sure, you are using same `ParentId` in `food` table to refer food for specific animal.

Hope, this make sense to you.

Comment: But how do I generate this ParentID when I add entries to the database?

Comment: which RDBMS are you using ?

Comment: sqlite, mysql, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If different animals eat the same kind of food, you should define a table with foreign keys the id of the two related tables:

```
CREATE TABLE animals (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE food (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, food TEXT);
CREATE TABLE eat (animal_id INTEGER, food_id INTEGER,
     FOREIGN KEY (animal_id) REFERENCES animals(id),
     FOREIGN KEY (food_id) REFERENCES food(id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an animal would eat multiple food and multiple animals could eat same food. You need to have a many-to-many association with animals and food.

```
Animal(id integer, name Text)
Food(id integer, name TEXT)
AnimalFood(animalId integer,foodId integer)

CREATE TABLE animals (id int(11) not null auto_increment primary key, name text);
CREATE TABLE foods (id int(11) not null auto_increment primary key, name text);
CREATE TABLE animal_foods (animal_id int(11) not null, food_id (11) not null);
```